# Parse into div where div id = json id

Tags: jquery, json

Hi I have a HTML document that contains some 'div's with an 'id'. I would like to parse from JSON where the 'div' 'id' is the same as the `id` from  the JSON.

Json:

```
'[{"id":c1,"value":"bla, bla"},{"id":c2,"value":"bla, bla"},{"id":c3,"value":"bla, bla"},{"id":c4,"value":"bla, bla"}]'
```

html(example)

```
<h1>
    <div id="c4"></div>
    <div id="c1></div>
    <p>Bla, bla, bla</p>
    <div id="c3"></div>
    <div id="c2"></div>
```

How can I replace the value to the correct div id?

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you know how to parse a JSON string? Do you know how to access a DOM element using jQuery? This is all you need really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like that,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var a=[
{"id":"c1","value":"bla, bla"},
{"id":"c2","value":"bla, bla"},
{"id":"c3","value":"bla, bla"},
{"id":"c4","value":"bla, bla"}
];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    $('#'+a[i].id).html(a[i].value)
}
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/srah2vgb/

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy Coding Mate.